# How to display struct with new println! format?

Tags: rust

In Rust 1.58, `println!("{x}");` is supported (Captured identifiers in format strings), but I cannot print the struct because I don't specify `{:?}`. Are there any ways to display struct with the new `println!`?

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Structure {
    name: String,
    version: u32
}

fn main() {
    let structure = Structure { name: "name".to_string(), version: 1 };
    println!("{:?}", structure); // working
    println!("{structure}");     // not working
}
```

Comment: For those wondering, the full format is `{thing_to_print:format_to_print_it}`, where `thing_to_print` is optional and defaults to the corresponding argument of the macro, other options are named arguments and positional arguments, and `format_to_print_it` is optional and defaults to using the `Display` trait, other options are `Debug` (whose symbol is `?`), but there are other traits, and other options for those traits (eg. to specify the number of decimals). The full format is defined at the [`std::fmt` module documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#formatting-traits).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add the `:?` debug modifier as part of the formatting as well:

```rust
println!("{structure:?}");
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4fa87a0ebdb5191bb0283a79b3d79a52)